# How do I open angular dynamic tabs with different dashboard components inside?

Tags: angular, dynamic, tabs

I've run into a problem with dynamic tabs that I haven't been able to find a good solution or good example on, so I hoping for a little help here.

I want visitors to my webpage to arrive at a frontpage where there is a table that list different organisations, and users belonging to that organisation. When visitors click on an organisation, a tab should open and display a dashboard component specific for organisations (i.e. a dashboard with cards with profile information that is relevant for the organisation). However, when the visitor clicks on a user, a tab should also open, but the screen displays a different dashboard component which is specific for showing user profiles. In my example stackblitz below, I've managed to set up the dynamic tabs and on the frontpage where there are buttons for 2 organisations and 3 users belonging to those 2 organisations.

The question now is how do I make the tabs for organisations show an organisational dashboard component, while the tabs for users show a user dashboard component?

Is there a way in the `addTab()` to add parameters, so that it doesn't only get the name of the new tab? For instance, it can also get what kind of dashboard the user wants to show in the new tab, i.e. 'user' or 'organisation'?

Or does Angular offer a better alternative for coding that?

Here is my example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhjjvb)

Comment: I see the stackblitz example, but I don't see the code behind the example. could you post that link please?

Comment: Sorry rhavelka - i'm apperently also a little new with Stackblitz. It should display with this little addition to the URL :)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhjjvb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a `context` variable on your tabs, so your tabs would look like this

```
{
  tabName: string,
  context: string,
}
```

and then in your html, you can use an `*ngIf` to check the context of if it is a client or organization

```
<app-app-dashboard *ngIf="tab.context == 'org'"></app-app-dashboard>
<app-client-dashboard *ngIf="tab.context == 'user'"></app-client-dashboard>
```

And that's all you should have to do. Here is the working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbjqjv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-client-dashboard%2Fapp-client-dashboard.component.ts). I added background colors to help you notice the difference between client vs org backgrounds.

Comment: MY GOD! So fast! Thank you so much. I had actually tried with the *ngIf in a slightly different way, but it didn't work for me, but I can see it was likely my setup in the addTab() function description in the ts-file. Thank you rhavelka! :)